# Как ловить ошибку и перенаправлять на другую страницы vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, router

Как отловить, что пользователь обновил страницу и перекинуть на другую? Читал доку [Режим HTML5 History](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2) как реализовать данную проблему на NODE. Как сделать это на фронте.

При обновление страницы на пути main/page1, страница не грузиться только если вернуться на main. Как реализовать переход на main при обновление?

> Возникает, однако, и проблема: поскольку наше приложение —
>   одностраничное, не сконфигурировав соответствующим образом сервер мы
>   заставим пользователей получать ошибку 404, если они перейдут по
>   http://oursite.com/user/id напрямую. Вот это уже прекрасным не
>   назвать.

Сделать через [Навигационные хуки](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#%D0%B3n%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0n%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%85%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%85%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2)? Как бы это выглядело? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Вот базовый пример router

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Login from '../components/Login.vue'


Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Login',
    component: Login
  },
  { 
    path: '*', 
    component: Login
  },   
  {
    path: '/todo',
    name: 'ToDo',
    component: () => import( '../components/ToDo.vue')
  },
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: '/',
  routes
})

router.beforeResolve((to, from, next) => {
  if (routes !== undefined) {
    next()
  } else {
    next({ path: '/login' })
  }
})


export default router
```

Или же это все лечиться через cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то вам нужно узнать перешли вы ли та эту страницу из другой или сайт включен уже на вашей странице. Тогда можно добавить в компонет станици такой хук:

```
beforeRouteEnter(from, to, next) {
  console.log(to.name === null); // true если страницу обновить на єтом роуте
  next();
}
```

И тогда уже запускать next('/');

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ. У меня проблема в том что при обновление страницы сайт вылетает (на бэке одна точка входа  www.a.ru) а руты www.a.ru/1 или  www.a.ru/2 разные. Стоит обновить страницу все отливается. Я хотел отловить этот момент и закидывать на  www.a.ru